# Why can’t conditional operator be used to conditionally increment property like this?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, jshint

Why do I receive a linter warning when using the conditional operator, but using a simple `if` statement does not?

### Incorrect

```js
switch (type) {
  case 'add':
    array[index]['Quantity'] += 1;
    // Error when using `++array[index]['Quantity']`
    
    break;

  case 'remove':
    array[index]['Quantity'] > 0 ? array[index]['Quantity'] -= 1 : null;
    // Error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression (no-unused-expressions)
    
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```

### Possible way

```js
switch (type) {
  case 'add':
    array[index]['Quantity'] += 1;
    
    break;
    
  case 'remove':
    if (array[index]['Quantity'] > 0) {
      --array[index]['Quantity'];
    }
    
    break;
    
  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: `array[index]['Quantity'] > 0 ? array[index]['Quantity'] -= 1 : null;` is like `if(array[index]['Quantity'] > 0){ array[index]['Quantity'] -= 1; } else { null; }`. `null;` is an expression statement whose value is never used. If you’re not using the return value of the conditional expression, then you’ll get the linter warning, because the expression itself is neither a function call nor an assignment — even if the expression has side-effects (but this won’t be statically analyzed).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the problem:

```
    array[index]['Quantity'] > 0 ? array[index]['Quantity']-=1 : 0;  // Error
    break;
```

You are returning an expression (array[index]['Quantity']-=1) when the ternary condition is true, when you should be returning a value.

Try this:

```
    array[index]['Quantity'] = array[index]['Quantity'] > 0 ? array[index]['Quantity'] - 1 : 0;
    break;
```

But I still think this is the best solution:

```
    if (array[index]['Quantity'] > 0)
         array[index]['Quantity']--;
    break;
```

Comment: That’s misleading. The original conditional expression also returns values. The point of the linter warning is that this return value is never used, even if part of the expression has side effects.

Comment: A shorter alternative would be `array[index].Quantity -= Number(array[index].Quantity > 0);`.